# c:if inside input component and data table

Tags: jsf-2

I have a custom component that uses c:if to determine the ajax to use:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="value" required="true" />
    <composite:attribute name="renderOnChange" type="java.lang.String"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
        <c:if test="#{not empty cc.attrs.renderOnChange}">
            <a4j:ajax event="change" render="#{cc.attrs.renderOnChange}" />
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="#{empty cc.attrs.renderOnChange}">
            <a4j:ajax event="change" render="#{somethingDifferent}" />
        </c:if>
    </h:inputText>
</composite:implementation>
```

The problem happens when I try to use the component in a data table because the c:ifs do not work. Is there a JSF equivalent that could be used to show the a4j:ajax depending on the attributes? I have tried ui:fragment, and a number of other ui tags to try to achieve this but none of them work inside the input component.

I would also like to use the same method to show f:validators.

Comment: what about `disable=#{yourcondition}` on the `a4j` tag?

Comment: I tried this, but it seems it is only working for the first a4j:ajax. On subsequent a4j:ajax tags, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Possible way is to create two `<h:inputText>` components then you can use the `rendered` attribute and place your condition from the `<c:if>` tags there.

Comment: Thank you Seraphstryfe, I was hoping there might be a tag similar to c:if that could be used inside an inputText to create sub elements, so that I don't have to repeat the code, but it looks like there isn't any. Thanks for your help and input.